# C++ array in Objective C gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.6 programming for iOS with ARC.

I am working with an array of simple integers and when using NSMutableArray it all works fine with the code below.

```
NSMutableArray *_array; // variable
...
_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity]; // allocation 
... 
[_array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:int_number]]; // inserting 
... 
return [[_array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]; // retrieving
```

This however does not perform that well as I am doing a lot of lookups in the array and all the unboxing and possible NSMutableArray itself is a bit slow.

In other parts of my code I have replaced the NSMutableArray with a simple c-array with great improvements, but in this part I am working with variable length arrays and cannot use a simple c-array. So I am trying with C++ arrays. In Xcode i rename the file from .m to .mm (to compile as Objective-C++) and use the code below which compiles fine but when it runs it causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors and I cannot find the reason. Do I need to do some manual garbage collection here?

```
int *_array; // variable
...
_array = new int[capacity]; // allocation
...
_array[i] = int_number; // inserting
...
return _array[i]; // retrieving
```

Comment: Can you show the line you are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on?

Comment: It changes. It is not on the same line every time.

Comment: `_array[i] = int_number;` is not inserting. You are overwriting the value at index `i`. Could that be the reason of your exception? You're not increasing the array.

Comment: Good point, but that is not the case here. I have that under control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say its a very safe guess to assume you accessed an element outside of the array, i.e. your `i` was `>= capacity`. And yes, you will have to eventually manually `delete[]` the array you allocated using `new`. Definitely from this snippet you posted it looks like it will leak, so maybe you want to provide the code more in context, like where variables are defined (locally or in a class or wherever) and how data is accessed, etc.

Comment: To add to this, definitely consider using either C++11 `std::shared_ptr<>` or `boost::shared_array<>` to take care of memory management for you.

Comment: Even better, if you do have access to C++11 features, might be the use of `std::array`, which should do bounds checking (not sure about how the state is under MacOS though).

Comment: MacOSX (and iOS) has had a C++11 capable `clang` as the default compiler (and corresponding C++ standard library) for quite a while - so all of these are options.

Comment: Yes, as it turned out. I did mess up the order of the capacity allocation and the initial insertions. So indeed I did try to access an space outside the array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You want *C++ variable-length arrays*?  Then [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is what you are after, not the *C arrays* you are attempting to use.

```
std::vector<int> _array; // variable
...
_array.reserve(capacity); // allocation
...
_array[i] = int_number; // inserting
...
return _array[i]; // retrieving
```

Comment: The std::vector turned out to perform well so I am going with that. Do I need to do any manual clean up here? Or can I count on the ARC to do this for me as I do all other places. Is the ARC still active when renaming to .mm?

Comment: No clean-up required and that's not because of the ARC; it's because of `vector::~vector()` :)  Yes, ARC still works with Objective-C++, but as I hint at; it's not involved at all with C++ classes.